# How can I use MS services without using MS OFFICE 365

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ms-word, office365, powerpoint

I am a Windows 10 Pro user. I used to work on normal Windows 10 and I had MS features like Word, PowerPoint & Excel services which were built-in inside Windows 10. Now that I updated my OS to Windows 10 pro, all the services are inside Office365, which is troublesome for me. Some files can not be opened as well.

Is there any way that I can setup/use MS EXCEL, PowerPoint & Word inside my OS like before? Office365 is not working for me well.

I tried downloading excel, word from MS website but they keep taking me OFFICE365, outlook services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10 Pro, you can install Microsoft Office as you would any other software. You can purchase a Microsoft Office license or use a trial version. Once you have installed Microsoft Office, you will have access to Word, Excel, and PowerPoint as separate applications.

Alternatively, you can use the online versions of these applications, which are available through Office 365. You can access these online versions by going to the Office website and signing in with your Microsoft account. You can use these online versions for free, but they do require an internet connection.

If you want to use the built-in Microsoft Office features that were available in previous versions of Windows, you can try using the Office Mobile apps. These apps are available for free from the Microsoft Store and allow you to view and edit Word, Excel, and PowerPoint documents on your device.

Finally, you can also try using alternative office suite applications, such as Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides, which are available for free and do not require a Microsoft account. These applications are web-based and can be accessed through a web browser